# How to show a message after clicking a button in Python TkInter?

Tags: python, tkinter, button

**I would to like to know how to show a message inside Tkinter.
I have this code but when i click the button, the message shows in Prompt.**

```
from tkinter import *

janela = Tk()
janela.title("Poemas")
texto = Label(janela, text="O que você quer ler hoje?")
texto.grid(column=0, row=0, padx=50, pady=50)

def botao_Click(mensagem):
    print(mensagem)

#1° botão
botao = Button(janela, text="Buscar poemas",command=lambda: botao_Click("Nova msg"))
botao.grid(column=0, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)

#2° botão
botao = Button(janela, text="Buscar poetas",command=lambda: botao_Click("outra msg"))
botao.grid(column=1, row=1, padx=10, pady=10)


janela.mainloop()
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0Qns.jpg)

Comment: Do you want to show it inside a new `Label` widget or update the contents of your `texto` widget?

Answer (score 1):

Change the

```
  def botao_Click(mensagem):
    print(mensagem)
```

to `def onClick(): tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Title goes here","Message goes here")`

And the button to

```
button = tkinter.Button(root,text = "Click Me", command = onClick)
```

The key is that the `print` method is to print to the console. `tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("","")` is for the popup message

Comment: Why did you rename the function? Why did you assume that OP wants to show the message in a new window? Also OP wants to be able to reuse the function to display different texts based on the button that is clicked.